# How this HTML5 animation generate?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

Do you have see this page http://google.github.io/tracing-framework/ , it's a amazing animation it there.

You guys know how to generate it ? I sure it isn't by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're using Javascript and this [image](http://google.github.io/tracing-framework/resources/anim_index.png) which is super huge(along with a few other images you can view in their resources. And you can see the source of one of their js files [here](http://google.github.io/tracing-framework/resources/all-animations.js).

btdubs - Yes - they ARE using canvas.

Not sure if that answers your question or you wanted something more specific.

Comment: Thanks! I'm find it animation generate FX https://github.com/sublimehq/anim_encoder from JS source code